# How to Edit a column (XtraGrid) only when adding a new row

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a column in my XtraGrid setup as follows:

```
var sampleColumn= GridControl1.ResultView.Columns.AddField(fieldSampleColumn);
sampleColumn.Caption = captionSampleColumn;
sampleColumn.VisibleIndex = GridControl1.ResultView.Columns.Count;
sampleColumn.Width = 175;
sampleColumn.OptionsColumn.ReadOnly = true;
```

What I would like is to make this column editable only when adding a new row to the grid.  In addition, I would like to use a RepositoryItemComboBox when editing this column on new rows.  The values in the combo will be specific to a column earlier in the row.

```
private readonly RepositoryItemComboBox _addSampleColumnValue = new RepositoryItemComboBox();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Okay, using [This Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17244501/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-cell-editable-where-column-is-readonly-in-xtragrid?rq=1) I was able to figure out how to get edit only when I want to, so that may point me in the right direction.